# How to propagate a chain of divs?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a series of statuses that I want to output that are outlined here with my divs:

```
<div>
<div id="startButtonDiv">
    <button id="Start" onclick="verifyAccount();">Start</button>
</div>
<div id="conversationDiv">
    <label>What is your name?</label><input type="text" id="name" />
    <button id="sendName" onclick="sendName();">Send</button>
    <p id="response"></p>
</div>
<div id="verifyAccountDiv">
    <label>Account verified</label>
    <button id="checkBillingButton" onclick="billing();">Check Billing</button>
</div>
<div id="billingDiv">
    <label>Billing checked</label>
    <button id="activationButton" onclick="activation();">Activate Device</button>
</div>
<div id="deviceActivationDiv">
    Device Activated!
</div>
```

Here are the functions that are called on the clicks:

```
function replaceDiv(oldDiv, newDiv) {
        document.getElementById(oldDiv).innerHTML = document.getElementById(newDiv).innerHTML; 

    }

    function verifyAccount() {
        sleep(500));//simulate authentication
        replaceDiv("startButtonDiv","verifyAccountDiv");
    }

    function billing() {
        sleep(500);//simulate billing
        replaceDiv("verifyAccountDiv", "billingDiv");
    }

    function activation() {
        sleep(500);//simulate device activation
        replaceDiv("billingDiv", "deviceActivationDiv");
    }
```

However, I only get to the first function call, verifyAccount(). Then when I click the check billing button, nothing happens. Is it because the div is replaced first? Does anyone see my problem?

Comment: Can you please specify **why** you would do that instead of simply hide/showing the different divs? As for the `onclick` attributes, yeah, you're not modifying the ID so that's the problem. But in any case this is a pretty awkward way of accomplishing such a feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're having this issue is that you aren't replacing the actual divs. Instead, you're replacing the *content* of the divs. In other words, when call the first function, `verifyAccount()`, you go from this:

```
<div id="startButtonDiv">
    <button id="Start" onclick="verifyAccount();">Start</button>
</div>
```

To this:

```
<div id="startButtonDiv">
    <label>Account verified</label>
    <button id="checkBillingButton" onclick="billing();">Check Billing</button>
</div>
```

Notice how the id of the div doesn't change from `startButtonDiv` to `verifyAccountDiv`. This is because instead of replacing the actual divs, you're only changing the content (this is what `.innerHTML` does).

In order to fix the issue, I recommend changing your JS functions, i.e.:

```
function billing() {
    sleep(500);
    replaceDiv("startButtonDiv", "billingDiv");
}

function activation() {
    sleep(500);
    replaceDiv("startButtonDiv", "deviceActivationDiv");
}
```

You could also replace the divs themselves, or change their IDs. However, if you ever want to go back, you'll run into problems. Additionally, I recommend you use a library if you're going to be going through lots of DOM editing with JS - it makes your code cleaner, easier to understand, and more reliable.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed my issue completely. A library sounds like a great idea, but I'm not sure how to implement one. Do you think you could lead me in the right direction?

Comment: Not most optimal solution, but certainly easiest & quickest. @Theo you should only use a library if you feel that it suits your needs. jQuery is easy to start with (easier than normal JS imho) but it's hard to break away from once you got used to it.

Answer (score -1):

If you are allowed to use JQuery here is how I would suggest to do that

**Working example is here** http://jsfiddle.net/pvkovalev/UB5Fs/

```
<div id="startButtonDiv">
    <button id="Start" class="status">Start</button>
</div>
<div id="conversationDiv">
    <label>What is your name?</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" />
    <button id="sendName" class="status">Send</button>
    <p id="response"></p>
</div>
<div id="verifyAccountDiv">
    <label>Account verified</label>
    <button id="checkBillingButton" class="status">Check Billing</button>
</div>
<div id="billingDiv">
    <label>Billing checked</label>
    <button id="activationButton" class="status">Activate Device</button>
</div>
<div id="deviceActivationDiv">Device Activated!</div>
```

and here is JavaScript

```
$(document).on('click', '.status', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    switch (id) {
        case 'sendName':
            verifyAccount();
            break
        case 'checkBillingButton':
            billing();
            break
        case 'activationButton':
            activation();
            break
        default:
            alert('default case!')
    }
});

function replaceDiv(data) {
    var html = $('#' + data).clone().html();
    $('#startButtonDiv').html(html)
}

function verifyAccount() {
    //simulate authentication
    setTimeout(function () {
        replaceDiv("verifyAccountDiv");
    }, 500);
}

function billing() {
    //sleep(500); //simulate billing

    setTimeout(function () {
        replaceDiv("billingDiv");
    }, 500);

}

function activation() {
    //sleep(500); //simulate device activation
    setTimeout(function () {
        replaceDiv("deviceActivationDiv");
    }, 500);

}
```

The code is far from perfect but you can get the main direction. Good luck!

Comment: Virtual -1 for requiring jQuery for such a basic task. Btw you don't really need all those functions, 1 would suffice, with a parameter of `ID` for each div

Comment: @Tyblitz I assume that project is more complicated than couple line of html :-) IMHO, Nowadays it is really hard to find a project which is not using jQuery or any other framework for DOM manipulation. :-) So you can downvote if you want :-)

Comment: No, it's not a bad solution, it *works*. jQuery is great, but the problem is that if everyone is encouraged to use it, no one will ever understand what he/she is actually doing in native Javascript (which has, now, thanks to jQuery, implemented similar methods like `querySelector`). And the truth is that jQuery is good for making lengthy things easy and short; but it is often overkill for basic functionality.

Comment: We can indeed; I, however, am downvoting because you chose to post a solution requiring a library to **a:** perform a simple task, and **b:** that isn't featured as a tag to the question. References: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40897/is-it-okay-to-post-answers-using-libraries-frameworks-extensions-not-already-ment and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91519/does-javascript-and-jquery-mean-the-same-thing.

Comment: @DavidThomas thank you sir! You explained me everything and I'm falling on my knees and accepting your punishment! :-)